# Click TouchableOpacity while TextInput is focused

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I'm currently working on a React Native App, where the user can type some text input and click "ok" to confirm. Next question appears. But at the moment i have to double click the button. First time the keyboard closes and second time the button is pressed. Same thing for iOS and android.
I already tried `keyboardShoulPersitsTaps='always'`and also `handled`, but nothing works.
I also tried to make every view above a scroll view and added this prop, but still no luck...

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: @DavidScholz  Here's a [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/IBR2VK3AZ). You have to select "Scondary Survey"

Comment: Can you please try `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"`. instead of `handled`?

Comment: As mentioned in the description, both doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nesting a `ScrollView` with a `KeyboardAwareScrollView`.

You need to set the `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` prop on the parent view as well. Consider the following code snippet from your snack.

```js
<KeyboardAwareScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef} onContentSizeChange={() => scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })} keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'>
            {steps.map(item => { return (<SingleAlgorithmStep key={item["Question"]} step={item} stepsDone={steps} clickedButtons={clickedButtons} algorithmJson={currentAlgorithmJson} actualizeSteps={(item) => updateSteps(item)} actualizeButtons={(item) => updateClickedButton(item)} />) })}
          </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

This fixed the issue on my device.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my issue

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the incorrect property name, `keyboardShouldPersistTabs`, instead of `keyboardShouldPersistTaps`.

```
<ScrollView
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
>
      ....
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Sorry, a tipo. Of course I meant ```keyboardShouldPersitsTaps```

Comment: As of the latest version of react native this is the better solution as it works out of the box with no  external libs